# Using end() with text based indexes

Tags: php, arrays, function

Can I trust end() to return the last index of an array even if the indexes are text based?

If the answer is yes, would it mean all arrays have a numerical index on them hidden "under the hood", an id of somesort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and yes.  PHP keeps track of the order that the array was defined (unless it is sorted or spliced etc. obviously).  The last element will be the last one that was defined:

```
$array[5] = 5;
$array[1] = 1;
$array[0] = 0;
print_r($array);
echo end($array);

$array['z'] = 'z';
$array['a'] = 'a';
$array['b'] = 'b';
print_r($array);
echo end($array);
```

As expected:

```
Array
(
    [5] => 5
    [1] => 1
    [0] => 0
)
0
Array
(
    [5] => 5
    [1] => 1
    [0] => 0
    [z] => z
    [a] => a
    [b] => b
)
b
```

Sorted:

```
sort($array);
print_r($array);
echo end($array);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => z
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 5
)
5
```

Since I've seen two of these questions today:  [Understanding PHP's internal array implementation](http://nikic.github.io/2012/03/28/Understanding-PHPs-internal-array-implementation.html)

Comment: And if it's sorted it will return the new last element or the original last element?

Comment: The new last element.

Comment: You should `reset()` the array pointer to be safe. Or wrap this in a function, so it works on a copy instead of the original array.

Comment: Thank you. I will accept your answer in 7 minutes. Have a nice evening Abra!